# PHP AND MySQL - Entire table column needs links instead of plain text

Tags: php, mysql, hyperlink, html-table

Basically what I'm doing is storing everything from my table into an array.
After that I go through it and select row by row and assign it to an array.
Then it goes through that array and puts it in the table, cell by cell, in a single row.

Now the last column of my table are links and they are the fourth and last column in the table and in the database. They're, just like they should, showing up as plain text, but I'd rather have them clickable (For ease of use).

Since the entire table (Except for the, in this case, 4 header items) is created by php code I would have no clue on how to change just the last bit to be a link.

Help would really be appreciated!

Code:

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Future_Mods";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die (mysql_error());

    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Mod</th>
        <th>Is Available</th>
        <th>Has Been Added</th>
        <th>Reason</th>
        </tr>";

        for($i = 0; $i < mysqli_num_rows($result); $i++) {

            echo "<tr>";

            $row_array = mysqli_fetch_row($result);

            for ($j = 0; $j < mysqli_num_fields($result); $j++) {
                echo "<td>" .$row_array[$j]. "</td>\n";

                }
            }

            echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Sidenote: `mysql_error()` should be using the `i-version` ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relatively simple:

```
while ($row = mysqlI_fetch_row($result)) {

    end($row); // move array pointer to end of array
    $key = key($row); // get key of current pointer element

    // update last item to be a link
    $row[$key] = '<a href="http://example.com/', $row[$key] , '">', $row[$key], '</a>';

    // dump out array as table cells    
    echo '<td>', implode('</td><td>', $row), '<td>';
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

This seems to do the trick.

I can also see the logic behind it, so that's something I learned now too.

Thanks for the help and quick response.

Have a good day/night.

Andro.

Answer (score 0):

This is a question of HTML formatting for your result set table.

If you happen to have a php variable $s that you are sure contains a URL, you can display the URL and make it clickable with php code like this:

```
 echo sprintf ('<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>', $s);
```

For example if $s has the value `http://stackoverflow.com/` this will yield the HTML text

```
 <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/" target="_blank">http://stackoverflow.com/</a>
```

One of your $row items will contain that URL. So you can render it with this sort of patten.